# DOL Starter (LE1D12P7) Tripping at end of ramp on table saw

Tags: table-saw, power-tools, electrical-requirements

This question has been closed in the Electrical and Home Improvement sites as its seen as not relevant so maybe you guys can help!

I have an old table saw with a Schneider Electric LE1D12P7 DOL Starter. I haven't run it in a few months, but plugged it in today (230V, 16A - Ireland based) and it trips just at the end of the ramp phase as the motor reaches its target speed.

I have attached some pictures below. I ran it without the starter cover on and can see that it is the LC1D12 contactor that is tripping. If I reset the starter and run it again, the same thing happens.

Here's a link to a video of the Table Saw starting up: [Table Saw Ramp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DPeroeIZuXNWs-7DursR7HPKCHdAy_zj/view?usp=sharing) and here's another link that shows the contactor tripping just as the motor reaches its target speed: [Table Saw Ramp (No DOL Cover)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g_ei3VL-PpRieyEidVuUvpche_KhOK-2/view?usp=sharing)

I've never had to do any real troubleshooting with this saw so any advice on connections to check/components to replace etc would be greatly appreciated. I'm not entirely sure what the operating principle of these DOL starters is so hopefully it is something simple and obvious that can be tweaked to fix it. I did try changing the ramp duration on the starter but the contactor is still tripping as the motor reaches its target speed. If you need more information, please ask. Thank you

[image: Table Saw]
[image: DOL Starter No Cover]
[image: DOL Starter Spec]
[image: Plug]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking! Well this is certainly within our wheelhouse but it's hard to say how much on-point feedback you might get on it given the specialist nature of the Q. This does strike me as potentially something a sparky could diagnose easily, if you want to investigate that option. If nobody else has anything useful that works I can suggest a couple of other things to try but I won't leave them yet as neither is exactly a textbook solution ^_^

Comment: I hate to ask, but have you checked the feel of the motor as you spin it by hand? Is there any binding/grinding? Does it need lube? One possibility is that it’s just hard enough to turn that it happens to trip when it finally gets going.

Comment: Could be a bad electrical circuit somewhere.  I have a large dust collector and it would start spinning up and never make it over the hump.  Turned out that my circuit breaker in the electrical box was bad and could not handle the start up load.